# Remove extra space above top horizontal scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am adding a horizontal scroll bar to the top of my div using only javascript. I would like to add a border directly above this scroll bar. It seems like there is extra space because of the added scroll bar. What can I do to remove this space?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.double-scroll').forEach(function(element) {
    doubleScroll(element);
  });
});

function doubleScroll(element) {
  const scrollbar = document.createElement("div");
  scrollbar.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  scrollbar.style.overflow = "auto";
  scrollbar.style.overflowY = "hidden";
  scrollbar.firstChild.style.width = element.scrollWidth + "px";
  scrollbar.firstChild.style.paddingTop = "1px";
  scrollbar.firstChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\xA0"));
  scrollbar.classList.add("double-scroll-bar");
  let running = false;
  // Keep scrollbar in sync when element size changes
  new ResizeObserver(() => {
    scrollbar.firstChild.style.width = element.scrollWidth + "px";
  }).observe(element);
  scrollbar.onscroll = function() {
    if (running) {
      running = false;
      return;
    }
    running = true;
    element.scrollLeft = scrollbar.scrollLeft;
  };
  element.onscroll = function() {
    if (running) {
      running = false;
      return;
    }
    running = true;
    scrollbar.scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft;
  };
  element.parentNode.insertBefore(scrollbar, element);
}
```

```css
.my-class {
  padding: 16px;
  border-left: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-right: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-bottom: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.double-scroll-bar {
  border-top: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-left: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-right: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class double-scroll">
  <p>TestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTesting</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What about setting `height`?

Comment: It seems like you created the element specifically in your JS. Why inserted this `\xA0` in your div?

Comment: I used another SO answer to find a solution to adding the top scroll bar, and that character came along for free. Thank you for pointing out the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div contains a white space `&nbsp;` which is inserted in your JS:

```js
scrollbar.firstChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\xA0'));
```

You can change that to an empty string instead to remove the height or use CSS to do so by setting the height to 0:

```css
.double-scroll-bar > div {
  height: 0;
}
```

I'd also suggest that you use a more specific CSS selector for the above by using a class name for the div. For example: `.scrollbar-inner`

Here is an example that works:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.double-scroll').forEach(function(element) {
    doubleScroll(element);
  });
});

function doubleScroll(element) {
  const scrollbar = document.createElement('div');
  scrollbar.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  scrollbar.style.overflow = 'auto';
  scrollbar.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
  scrollbar.firstChild.style.width = element.scrollWidth + 'px';
  scrollbar.firstChild.style.paddingTop = '1px';
  scrollbar.firstChild.className = 'scrollbar-inner';
  scrollbar.firstChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\xA0'));
  scrollbar.classList.add('double-scroll-bar');
  let running = false;
  // Keep scrollbar in sync when element size changes
  new ResizeObserver(() => {
    scrollbar.firstChild.style.width = element.scrollWidth + 'px';
  }).observe(element);
  scrollbar.onscroll = function() {
    if (running) {
      running = false;
      return;
    }
    running = true;
    element.scrollLeft = scrollbar.scrollLeft;
  };
  element.onscroll = function() {
    if (running) {
      running = false;
      return;
    }
    running = true;
    scrollbar.scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft;
  };
  element.parentNode.insertBefore(scrollbar, element);
}
```

```css
.my-class {
  padding: 16px;
  border-left: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-right: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-bottom: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.double-scroll-bar {
  border-top: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-left: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-right: 24px solid #2c2c2c;
}

.scrollbar-inner {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class double-scroll">
  <p>
    TestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTesting
  </p>
</div>
```